# PhoneGap navigator.notification.alert does not work on iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app, phonegap-cli

I am new to PhoneGap and my navigator.notification.alert does not work. 
I am using a sample project from PhoneGap, just modified couple of lines in config.xml and in index.html

Problem is that alert is shown if I use **PhoneGap Developer**, but if I upload zip to **build.phonegap.com** and install an app -> alert is not shown

config.xml:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0">
  <name>HW</name>
  <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" version="1"/>
  <feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
  </feature>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

and index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='navigator.notification.alert("Fine!", null, "blablabla", "OK");'>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is wrong? Thank you

Comment: are you still having an issue?

Comment: Yes. I still cannot make an alert

Comment: okay give me some time to read your post.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexey
this is a common problem with the documentation. I have asked [Phonegap to fix it](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-docs/issues/137) but the have not.

The answer is you CANNOT use *Phonegap Build* in place of *Phonegap Desktop/Developer App*. They are meant to work together.

You can use either

- *Phoengap CLI*
- **OR**
- *Phonegap Build*

*Phonegap Build* requires two (2) files - `index.html` and `config.xml` and nothing else. It does **not** work with *Phonegap Developer App*.

*Phonegap CLI* is part of  *Phonegap Desktop App*. You can use *Phonegap CLI*, but never use *Phonegap Developer App* again.

To be clear:

- *Phonegap Build* and *Phonegap CLI* are for making standalone apps.
- *Phonegap Desktop App* and *Phonegap Developer App* work together.

When you have finished with *Phonegap Desktop App* - you are done with it. Do not use it again. Move to *Phonegap Build* or *Phonegap CLI*. I trust this is clear.

Comment: This does not make my case clear... How should the app for _Phonegap Build_ be created? With CLI? My application was initially created with CLI. I was checking it on the phone with _Phonegap Developer App_

Comment: That was not your question. Your question was: *What is wrong?* I have answered that question. --  To be clear, there is an answer to your new question, but you are asking a new question. You can now - ask a new question on stackoverflow or ask the question on another forum. I suggest [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap). Please link to the new question so I can respond.

Comment: Questions topic is "PhoneGap navigator.notification.alert does not work on iOS"

Comment: No. In English, that is a statement, not a question. Decide what you want to do. Do not argue.

Comment: It's probably just missing the "Why" at the start. Is everything clear now Alexey?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect the OP asked a new question, as directed. Please keep threads on-topic.

Comment: Please explain how my post is off topic. I'm trying to help and if the question is formulated poorly, but I still understand it, what's wrong with helping with the clarity?

Comment: No I won't. Quit wasting people's time. Ask a new question.